# How to build a url to direkt open office365 calendar of a tenant user?

Tags: web, office365

I am displaying a list of the tenant users as telephonebook on a intranet site. I want to embed a link to the calendars webview of each user in the list.

I can not figure out the format of the url nor find material.

Any hint or idea is appreciated.

I tried

```
https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/<email>/

https://outlook.office365.com/mail/<email>/
```

and experimented with the IDs I found in the api or subscription E-Mails.

What I want, when clicking the link for user B, is to open a browser tab with the calender of B optional asking for my credentials.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?